# Delegate call in Solidity - Proxy Pattern

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm writing upgradable Smart Contracts with the Proxy Design Pattern. Here, I'm facing a challenge when I make a delegate call from the proxy contract to the logic contract methods, it throws me an error message as below.
[image]

I'm wondering what I have done wrong.

The below code is the method call in the proxy contract.

```
  /*Delegates calls to the Logic contract*/
    function setAccepted()  public returns(Status){

        emit setToAccept(status,now,msg.sender);
        bool success;
        bytes memory result;

        (success,result) = delegateContract.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("setAccepted()"))));
        require(success);
        status = abi.decode(result, (Status));
        return status;

    }
```

Logic contract code as below.

```
function setAccepted() public _WhenNoPaused returns(Status){
       return Status.Accepted;
   }
```

Comment: Please provide your source code and specify which function did you call

Comment: @StillFantasy- I have shared my source code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is checked overall solidity code. I recommend studying a tutorial on proxy patterns in solidity. I attached a tutorial link.
https://github.com/rhcproc/solidity-proxy-tutorial
And I found several blogs that explained proxy patterns in solidity.

- https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies
- https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/proxy_delegate.html
- https://runtimeverification.com/blog/using-foundry-to-explore-upgradeable-contracts-part-1/